# Adding and Updating Photos added to Movie

Tags: imovie

Is there a feature that will allow photos added to a movie to be udated automatically when the image is updated in the asset library, so everything wont need to be recut.

There are about 60 images and they are synced to music.
Using iMovie 10.

Comment: I have tried using images from the main movie assets collection and iPhoto, then updating the image in the collection but the old image still remains in the main video editor. I don't see any way to do mass image updates without recutting everything.

Comment: A [quick google search](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2641769?tstart=0) shows this seems the expected behaviour in iMovie.

Comment: Seeking an alternative way, a solution.